# Is a .NET Standard DLL binary compatible with a .NET Framework one?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I currently have a utilities library built as .NET Framework 4.6.1 and referenced by various .NET Framework applications.

I now want to create a new .NET Core application and therefore I want to convert the utilities library to .NET Standard 2.0 so that it can be used by applications of both types.

If I simply open the source code for the library, change the target to .NET Standard 2.0 and rebuild it (assuming that it does only use APIs available in .NET Standard), can I just drop the new assembly in to replace the existing one and should the existing applications still work? Or would the applications need to be rebuilt against the new version?

And the more general related question is, what are the differences in the metadata produced for a .NET Standard DLL compared to a .NET Framework one, and how/if do they affect the assembly resolver?

(to pre-empt the comment "why not just try it and see", I want to know if this is a supported scenario, not just whether technically it might work for me)

Comment: The metadata format of .NET assemblies has been v4.0.40319 for the past 8 years.  That is not the problem, what is very different between .netstandard, .netframework and .netcore are the reference assemblies.  They heavily use type-forwarding to map types from the reference assembly to the runtime assembly.  This used to be understandable but got convoluted with forwarding happening not just at compile-time but at runtime as well.  Very hard to get a warranty that this ends well when you only rebuild that one assembly.  Try it, don't assume success.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*.Net Standard* is a compatible cross-section between (but not limited to) *.Net Framework* and *.Net Core*

Think of it like this

[image]

Or, one of the more standard propaganda pictures

[image]

There are lot of things in .Net Framework that just doesn't make a lot of sense in .Net Core. Windows specific things for instance.

However, what you can do is use [The .NET Portability Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer) to work out any glaring compatibility problems

> Want to make your libraries multi-platform? Want to see how much work
>   is required to make your application compatible with other .NET
>   implementations and profiles, including .NET Core, .NET Standard, UWP,
>   and Xamarin for iOS, Android, and Mac? The .NET Portability Analyzer
>   is a tool that provides you with a detailed report on how flexible
>   your program is across .NET implementations by analyzing assemblies.
>   The Portability Analyzer is offered as a Visual Studio Extension and
>   as a console app.

And here is another picture (of the tool), because it makes my post look detailed

[image]

**To answer your question**

> If I simply open the source code for the library, change the target to
>   .NET Standard 2.0 and rebuild it, can I just drop the new assembly in
>   to replace the existing one and should the existing applications still
>   work? Or would the applications need to be rebuilt against the new
>   version?

Needs to be rebuilt as far as i know, try it see what happens and let us know.

There are so many things that could make this not work.

> And the more general related question is, what are the differences in
>   the metadata produced for a .NET Standard DLL compared to a .NET
>   Framework one, and how/if do they affect the assembly resolver?

Not entirely sure what you mean, however it will resolve just the same when rebuilt.

> (to pre-empt the comment "why not just try it and see", I want to know
>   if this is a supported scenario, not just whether technically it might
>   work for me)

Just replacing the assembly is not supported as far as i know or could research. However maybe someone else has more information here.

Comment: that's all true but it doesn't answer the question

Comment: @gallivantor i preempted that, give me a sec updating

Comment: Though he didn't answer the question specifically, he already provided the tool which can be used for checking the compatibility. It is more useful than a specific answer.

Comment: thanks, do you have a reference in any official MS docs for these answers?

Comment: @gallivantor i have just searched everywhere i could for the last 30 minutes to see if this is actually officially supported, there is nowhere to say it is, BUT there is nowhere to say it isn't. I do know even when recompiling and msBuild you have to have the right version or it wont work on the best of days and there is also all sorts of steps to make this work. i know standard libraries will also have .net standard dependencies and binding isnt going to work in a lot of cases form the host application if it relies on any 3rd party libraries in your library. All i can say is try it

Comment: thanks, yeah I couldn't find any official MS docs either. Unfotunately all the docs seem to be about how to use .net core/standard, and there's not much documentation about how it actually works under the hood and therefore what the impact is in scenarios like this