# System.IO.FileLoadException when trying to test Entity Framework Core using MSTest - why?

Tags: mstest, entity-framework-core-3.1

I cannot unit test an Entity Framework Core project using MSTest.

When I do, I always get the following exception when I execute the test:

```
Test method "EF_Tests.CreateDbTests.CreateDb" threw exception: 
    System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

---

#### Here's my project structure and settings:

[image: Visual Studio 2019 project structure]

[image: Visual Studio 2019 project structure]

---

#### Here's my project files' content:

**Repository.csproj**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**EF-DB.csproj**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>EF_DB</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Repository\Repository.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**EF-Tests.csproj**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{538D0C25-637D-4CDF-BDBC-26AEEB9117FD}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>EF_Tests</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>EF-Tests</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">15.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <ReferencePath>$(ProgramFiles)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\$(VisualStudioVersion)\UITestExtensionPackages</ReferencePath>
    <IsCodedUITest>False</IsCodedUITest>
    <TestProjectType>UnitTest</TestProjectType>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="CreateDbTests.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\EF-DB\EF-DB.csproj">
      <Project>{c6c34842-8e25-4bcb-a20a-6c415baa008e}</Project>
      <Name>EF-DB</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Repository\Repository.csproj">
      <Project>{b4e6eeda-2439-4674-b127-0fbf91b90a08}</Project>
      <Name>Repository</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter">
      <Version>2.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework">
      <Version>2.1.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TeamTest\Microsoft.TestTools.targets" Condition="Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\TeamTest\Microsoft.TestTools.targets')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Please show the contents of your csproj files.

Comment: @granadaCoder: Thanks for taking up my question. I added the .csproj files' content now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I thought.  Your test csproj is all "frameworked" up.

You want something like this: (which comes from a .net CORE mstest project) (see images below)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Chronos.Abstractions" Version="2.0.24" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="2.8.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="5.10.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.2.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="PasswordGenerator" Version="2.0.5" />
  </ItemGroup>





</Project>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all: Thanks a lot for pointing me to the right direction!  I'm currently converting an EF6 sample project to EFC. --- Still, I got one question left: I used .NET Standard 2.0 as the project type for the other projects. So, why isn't my first version working as expected? It should, shouldn't it? .NET Standard 2.0 should be working in both worlds, shouldn't it?

Comment: It depends. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980861/is-a-net-standard-dll-binary-compatible-with-a-net-framework-one/52980913#52980913

Comment: This still is strange ... The .NET Framework project (i.e. EF-Test) is the _consuming_ project; i.e. the last in the line. The other, supporting, projects don't expose anything else than .NET Standard. ... I guess it must have something to do with how assemblies from referenced packages get bundled by a .NET Framework vs. .NET Core project's output (i.e. `\bin\ ` directory).

Comment: I don't know.  But reminds me when the original dotnetFW said it could do vb6ish COM objects.  I gave up on that voodoo.  :)